# React setState takes 200ms+

Tags: reactjs, performance, asynchronous, state

I'm listening to a websocket which triggers a callback once per second:

`setState1` happens every second, `setState2` also happens every second after 10 seconds and allows `LargeChildComponent` to display.

I found that updating this state was taking over 200ms.

[image: Slow setState console logs and Performance tab]

```
const myWebsocketCallback = async(newData) => {
  dataRef.current = [...dataRef.current, newData]

  const start = performance.now()
  setDataState(dataRef.current)
  console.log('setState', performance.now() - start)

  doWorkWithNewData()
}
```

So setting state was slow initially, and is extra slow when `LargeChildComponent` is rendering.

---

I found that moving a large JSON object from a state initialization to a init useEffect() reduced that time greatly.

```
- const [myBigData, setMyBigData] = useState(VERY_LARGE_JSON_OBJECT)

+ const [myBigData, setMyBigData] = useState()
+ useEffect(() => {
+   setMyBigData(VERY_LARGE_JSON_OBJECT)
+ }, [])
```

[image: Faster setState console logs and Performance tab]

**Is default state value checked every render?** Should I be initializing state in a useEffect(myFunc, [])?

---

The above change alone made a MASSIVE improvement.

However, that `setState()` is still taking 80ms+, AND it seems to be dependent on the size of the render (child components).

I was under the impression that `setState()` is an `async` task and should happen quickly regardless of any components which depend on it.

**Why is it still taking 80ms to update state?**

Is it due to being inside a callback function? Does state actually wait for children to render?

Comment: try `useState(() => very_large_object)`.  You may be seeing the side effects of actually allocating and destroying that large object on every render even when it is only needed to init state on the first render.  Passing a factory method to useState avoids the unnecessary cost of an expensive initiialization on each render.

Comment: @Brandon thanks for the suggestion. I wasn't aware that was an option and seems to have the same effect as the init useEffect approach. Any thoughts on the second part and it still being pretty slow, around 80ms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anytime you call setState outside of a React lifecycle method (React event handler or render function or effect) then it tends to *block* while React re-renders everything.  In React 18 they are making changes to the way state changes and renders are batched.

You can either:

Update to React 18 `createRoot` to get automatic batching

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from 'App';

const container = document.getElementById('root');

// Create a root.
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);

// Initial render
root.render(<App name="Saeloun blog" />);

// During an update, there is no need to pass the container again
root.render(<App name="Saeloun testimonials" />);
```

or use the `unstable_batchUpdate` method in React < 18

```js
import { unstable_batchedUpdates } from 'react-dom'

const myWebsocketCallback = async(newData) => {
  dataRef.current = [...dataRef.current, newData]

  const start = performance.now()
  unstable_batchUpdates(() => {
    setDataState(dataRef.current)
  })
  console.log('setState', performance.now() - start)

  doWorkWithNewData()
}
```

Comment: Attempting to use `unstable_batchUpdate` sped up the operation itself but kept the entire process in the same slow state. I'm not sure how far up the chain I'd have to move it to actually increase performance.
However, updating to React 18 (and presumably batching everything correctly automatically) has solved my issue!
I appreciate you pointing out the exceptions to React's normal batching.